# How do I reset a password in google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect to Google cloud using Putty. I got the public/private keys to work, but when I connect, it asks for a password. It will not accept the password for the private key or my Google log in or my email log in. I am try to either reset the password or ideally disable prompt for password using the console. None of the entries below were successful and resulted in  a series of error messages including:

```
Positional argument deprecated_host has been removed. Use --host instead.
```

How do I reset or cancel the password?

```
gcloud sql users set-password james_celentano –instance=instance-1 --prompt-for-password=off

Big problems “Positional argument deprecated_host has been removed”

gcloud sql users set-password --host –instance=instance-1 --prompt-for-password=off
```

Now does not like `--prompt-for-password=off`

```
gcloud sql users set-password --host –instance instance-1 -- password=

gcloud sql users set-password --host –instance= instance-1 –i instance-1 -- password=

gcloud sql users set-password james_celentano --host –instance=instance-1 password=

gcloud sql users set-password --host –instance=instance-1 password=

gcloud sql users set-password --host –instance=instance-1 –i=instance-1  password=
```

Answer (score 0):

The command to be used is:

```
gcloud sql users set-password postgres -i instance_test --prompt-for-password
```

As explained in the Google Cloud SDK [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/users/set-password).

Below there's an example where I typed the password after the prompt and then used it to connect to the database engine.

```
user@cloudshell:~ (projid)$ gcloud sql users set-password postgres -i instance_test --prompt-for-password                                                               
Instance Password:
Updating Cloud SQL user...done.
user@cloudshell:~ (projid)$ gcloud sql connect dbtest -u postgres                                                                                                
Whitelisting your IP for incoming connection for 5 minutes...done.
Connecting to database with SQL user [postgres].Password for user postgres:
psql (9.6.11, server 9.6.10)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits: 128, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

postgres-> \q
```